# Finding the even and odd numbers in a linked list by recursion?

Tags: recursion, linked-list

Happy new years for everyone! :)

I could do better things in the first day of the year but i'm trying to implement the linked lists and recursion together.

I just thought that how I can achieve to write a function that calculates the even numbers in a linked list with recursion.

```
void List:: findingEvens(Node* n, Node*& newHead){
    if(n  == NULL)
        return;
    else
        if(n-> data % 2 != 0)
            findingEvens(n-> next);
    else{
        if(!newHead){
            newHead = n;
        }
        else{
             Node* temp =head;
             for(;temp->next;temp=temp->next){
                temp = temp -> next;
              }
             temp-> next = n;
             findingEvents(n-> next);
        }
    }  
}
```

The problem is that in my h class I add the following as it should be

```
void findingEvens(Node* n);
```

However this makes me error which says that error: ‘Node’ has not been declared
Actually I have a Node struct after the definition of this function in h class.

Is the implementation of the recursive function wrong?
Any help will be appreciated, happy new year again :)

Comment: In the last `else` clause, it never does anything with `n->data`. You need to save the number found and then recurse on `n->next`.

Comment: Oh yes, thats true but how I store the n -> data, is the way creating a new list? actually i wanted to do all things in the given linked list.

Comment: Two ways: 1) Take a 2nd list as a parameter, add the found numbers to it. 2) Return an empty list from base case, even case adds the found number to the list returned by recursive call and returns it, odd case just returns the list from the recursive call.

Comment: O hi @Barmar i made some changes on this code can you please make a comment about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void List:: findingEvens(Node* n, Node*& newHead){
    if(n  == NULL)
        return;
    else
        if(n-> data % 2 != 0)
            findingEvens(n-> next, newHead);
    else{
        // Push even node onto newHead list
        newNode = new Node;
        newNode->data = n->data;
        newNode->next = newHead;
        newHead = newNode;
        findingEvens(n-> next, newHead);
    }
}
```

You need to pass `newHead` in the recursive calls.

You can't just assign `n` directly to `newHead`, because then the `newHead` list will have all the links from the original list. You need to make new nodes and copy the data.

The above code builds the result list in reverse order of the original list, e.g. if you start with `1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9`, the result will be `8, 6, 2`.  You can reverse the list when it's done.

Comment: So you're adding always before the head? Am i true?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. Adding to the end of the list is complicated, because you have to search the list for the end, or use another variable with a pointer to the end. You could also use a vector to hold the results, instead of a linked list.

Comment: Oh I see actually in this piece of code I was trying to add to the end? Doesn't it work?                                         for(;temp->next;temp=temp->next)
                temp = temp -> next;
                temp-> next = n;

Comment: It looked wrong because of your indentation (try to remember to put `{}` around everything) and because you used a nonexistent variable `head`, but I think it's OK when you fix those things.

Comment: And also I've a problem about calling the function in the main? What should I wrote for the (Node* n, Node*& newHead) parameters?

Comment: Oh sorry for the {}. Im adding them.

Comment: `Node *result = 0; List::findingEvens(list, result);`

Comment: This is getting a bit too basic; SO is not a programming tutoring site.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right thanks for all your help :) That's enough for me. Thanks a lot again.